# How to get MSSQL output from a procedure using PHP_PDO using FreeTDS driver and unixODBC

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures, pdo, freetds

I have been trying to get my head around returning an output from an MS SQL by using PHP_PDO ODBC using FreeTDS

MY Config for FreeTDS are as follows

```
Compile-time settings (established with the "configure" script)
                        Version: freetds v0.95.95
         freetds.conf directory: /usr/local/Cellar/freetds/0.95.95/etc
 MS db-lib source compatibility: no
    Sybase binary compatibility: no
                  Thread safety: yes
                  iconv library: yes
                    TDS version: 7.3
                          iODBC: no
                       unixodbc: yes
          SSPI "trusted" logins: no
                       Kerberos: no
                        OpenSSL: yes
                         GnuTLS: no
```

This procedure to be executed, How to i get value of @Identity

```
    DECLARE 
        @Identity varchar(50),
        @Header_DocNo int

EXEC    Patient_Invoice
        @Header_ID = N'-1',
        @Header_PatientID = N'CP.1',
        @Header_UserID = N'COP.1',
        @Identity = @Identity OUTPUT,
        @Header_DocNo = @Header_DocNo OUTPUT,
        @Hosp_Code = N'COP',
        @Header_RandomNo = N'-1'

SELECT  @Identity as N'@Identity',
        @Header_DocNo as N'@Header_DocNo'
```

This is my PHP function for calling the MS SQL procedure.

```
 public function postHeaderInvoice($data) {
    if (!empty($data) && is_array($data)) {
        $procedure = "Exec Patient_Invoice @Header_ID = ?, @Header_PatientID = ?,  @Header_UserID = ?,"
                . " @Header_DocNo =?, @Hosp_Code = ? , @Header_RandomNo = ?,  @Identity = 0";
        $query = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($procedure);
        $query->bindValue(1, $data['Header_ID'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindValue(2, $data['Header_PatientID'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindValue(3, $data['Header_UserID'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindValue(4, $data['Header_DocNo'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $query->bindValue(5, $data['Hosp_Code'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindValue(6, $data['Header_RandomNo'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        try {
            $execute = $query->execute();
        } catch (CDbException $e) {
            $this->result = $this->sanitizeException($e);
        }
    }
}
```